# Center Element at Bottom of Screen for Toast

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a toast element that appears at the bottom middle of the screen. Currently it appears at the bottom right of the screen:

```html
<div class="fixed flex items-center w-full max-w-xs p-4 bottom-5 left-5">
    <div class="max-w-xs bg-white border rounded-md shadow-lg">
        <div class="flex p-4">
            <CheckIcon />
            <div class="ml-3">
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-700">
                    {props.message}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sort of following the Flowbite theory of positioning:

https://flowbite.com/docs/components/toast/#positioning

But with my own components. Flowbite's examples only show right or left bottom, not middle bottom.

How can this be done in the bottom middle, not right or left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the code by removing the `max-w-xs` and `left-5` classes and adding the `justify-center` class to the fixed element. This will bottom/center the content horizontally on the page.

Here's the updated code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.0.5/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- tailwindcss -->

<div class="fixed flex justify-center items-center w-full p-4 bottom-5">
    <div class="max-w-xs bg-white border rounded-md shadow-lg">
        <div class="flex p-4">
            <CheckIcon />
            <div class="ml-3">
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-700">
                    message
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great to hear that it worked! You're welcome.